# Check if a git repository has any content that is not present in a remote

Tags: git

Given a git repository `maybe-old` and a remote `central-repository`.

Is there a way to quickly (automatically) check whether there are any commits or other content that is present in `maybe-old` that is not present in `central-repository`?

I want to know if I can delete `maybe-old` with no loss of information, including any local branches or tags that were not merged or pushed to the remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it depends.  If you've used a rebase-based workflow, then the obvious approaches aren't going to work, and you need something a little more complicated.  However, if you're okay with that limitation, then here's how I'd do it (only lightly tested):

```
#!/bin/sh

tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)

# Make sure we have all of the objects from the remote repository.
git fetch central-repository

# Enumerate each revision reachable from a ref under refs/heads and
# refs/tags and save it in a file.
git ls-remote central-repository refs/heads/* refs/tags/* | awk '{print $1}' | \
    xargs git rev-list > $tmpdir/remote-revs

# Enumerate the commit for each ref in this repository and find any
# that are not in the list of remote revisions.
if git for-each-ref | awk '{print $1}' | grep -f $tmpdir/remote-revs -qsvF
then
    echo "Oh, no!  Missing commits!"
else
    echo "Up to date."
fi
```

If you've used a rebase-based workflow, then your life is going to be a little harder.  You might be able to `git rev-list --objects` in both cases to find all objects on both sides and compare, but you may still end up with problems if your changes have been incorporated but the blobs aren't exactly the same.  You can try `git cherry` in that case, but it also has limitations that can mark commits as missing when they're not.

Comment: Thanks! This is very good. I did a bit of a clean up here: https://github.com/luispedro/git-contained (crediting you)